# Using Apple Shortcuts app output

Tags: applescript, shortcuts-app

I must be missing something with Apple Shortcuts.

Once you have a result, how can you get it written in the application you're using if it's not an application in Shortcuts catalogue ?

Let's say for the sake of simplicity I want to use a shortcut that writes my name at the cursor location in my application

At some point I can finish the shortcuts "program" with
`copy text to clipboard`

At that point I only need to press cmd-V to get it done

But what if I want Shortcut to do it ?

I can't figure it out

I could maybe get an AppleScript to use system events to do it but this seems overkill.

Any idea ?

Comment: To control the keyboard, you are looking at running a script.

Comment: Not really, I am hoping that I could get a script to achieve its results, without the need to complete it by an additional keyboard stroke.

Comment: Yes, you would need to use something like Run AppleScript to control the keyboard (perform the keystroke).

Comment: Actually, all I want is getting the output of the shortcut inside my app. I suggested using the clipboard then the keyboard, or alternatively running an AppleScript to send system events (which I understand is similar to your comment about controlling the keyboard). So your point is that it is the only way ?

Comment: Well, to use System Events you would need to use an AppleScript, but couldn’t you also use a Run AppleScript to launch the app with the appropriate arguments, or have the app just get the clipboard itself?

Comment: The point of the question is to leverage the power of Shortcuts and get a result that could be used anywhere on my Mac; if I need to a) remember that I need to complete the shortcut by Cmd V or b) write it in AppleScript in the first place or c) write an additional AppleScript that needs to know in which app it should be used, it defeats the purpose.

Comment: It is the same with Automator.  When you want to do something that there isn’t an action for, you wind up using a script, which defeats the purpose of using Automator.

Comment: I never really understood Automator, but I would have expected Shortcuts to be more powerful and be able to process text in place, without scripting keystrokes.

Comment: _Shortcuts_ isn't more powerful than _Automator_: it's essentially _Automator_ that's had its bollocks chopped off.  _Shortcuts_ is Apple's answer to how to polish a turd.  To achieve what you want, it has to be done in _Automator_,  as a Quick Action, where there's an option you must tick at the top of the workflow called something _"Output Replaces Selection"_.

Comment: Ok. I’m not sure I condone the language but thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Given the answers received, I consider the topic closed.
On top of that, using an apple script is not as difficult as I imagined

You only need to add two shortcuts steps:

```
Get Clipboard
Execute AppleScript
```

with the corresponding script

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "v" using {command down}
        return input
    end tell
end run
```